Transform mongo messages from Kafka using debezium JdbcSinkConnector
I send events from MongoDB using Debezium connector for MongoDB to Apache Kafka. The message looks like this:
"schema": {...},
"payload": {
    "before": null,
    "after": "{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"6613f1b16344a5046d883b63\"},\"id\": 100500,\"shipment_id\": 123,\"orders\": [{\"id\": 14,\"quantity\": 56},{\"id\": 15,\"quantity\": 51,\"size\": 171717}],\"shipmentsIds\": [],\"properties\": {\"p1\": 1,\"p2\": \"at1\"}}",
    "updateDescription": null,
    "source": {
      "version": "2.5.0.Final",
      "connector": "mongodb",
      "name": "data",
      "ts_ms": 0,
      "snapshot": "last",
      "db": "adb",
      "sequence": null,
      "rs": "rs0",
      "collection": "shipments3",
      "ord": -1,
      "lsid": null,
      "txnNumber": null,
      "wallTime": null
    },
    "op": "r",
    "ts_ms": 1712668133042,
    "transaction": null
  }


The after key in payload consists of json string with array orders and other required fields.
And I'd like to insert this messages to target postgres DB using Debezium sink connector for JDBC. I use the folowing config for sink connector:
{
    "name": "sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "data.adb.shipments",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.50.20:6432/postgres",
        "connection.username": "postgres",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "connection.password": "123456",
        "insert.mode": "insert",
        "table.name.format": "public.shipments",
        "schema.evolution": "basic",
        "batch.size": 5000,
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.ExtractNewDocumentState",
        "transforms.unwrap.array.encoding": "array",
        "transforms.unwrap.flatten.struct": "false"
    }
}


I want to insert after key in payload section to corresponding field in postgres table. And then parse it using postgres json syntax.
I register this config using the following command:
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d  @jdbc-mongo-sink.json localhost:8083/connectors/

But after resistering, I get an error from sink connector like Can't parse the message. What am I doing wrong?

Wrt "But then I try it, I get an error from sink connector" - Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a minimal reproducible example.
